# Can you search for how many times a words occurance appears in a sentence and give both positions of the words?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to find a single word in a sentence and show its position. with the following:

```
sentence= input("Write a sentence with two words the same: ")
findme = input("Type a word that appears twice: ")
words = sentence.split()
print (list(enumerate(words)))
print ("The length of sentnce in chracters is",len(sentence))
t = words
print("third word in sentence is:", t[2]) 
if sentence.find(findme)!=-1:
    print("found word")
else:
    print("word not found")
    print (sentence.find(findme))
    numberofwords = len(t)
    print("The amount of words in the sentence is:",numberofwords,"words.")
    print("This is the last time",findme,"is found in the sentence, its at",sentence.rfind(findme))
    print (sentence.index(findme))

test_words = sentence.split()
position = test_words.index(findme)
position = position +1


if position == 1:
    addtoword = "st"
elif position == 2:
    addtoword = "nd"
elif position == 3:
    addtoword = "rd"
elif position >=4:
    addtoword = "th"

print ("The word",findme,"is the",position,addtoword,"and     position",position,"word in the sentence.")

print ("The word",findme,"appears",sentence.count(findme),"times in the     sentence provided.")
```

But I want to simplify and display the location of the repeated word for example
in " The cat sat on the mat with another cat."  would return " The word Cat occurs 2 times, once at 2nd position then at 9th position.

Comment: Please fix the indentation, it will make your code much easier to read (and also make it a syntactically valid Python program).

Comment: Yes, you can - store all of the locations in a list, then use its `len` for the count and iterate over it for the locations.

Answer (score 0):

Using `collection`'s [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

sent = "The cat sat on the mat with another cat."
# lower the sentence, strip it from punctuation and split
l = sent.lower().strip('?!.,').split()
# create Counter and find most common word
word = Counter(l).most_common(1)[0][0]                  # 'the'
# find positions with the word
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x == word]     # [0, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe suggested, you can store all of the locations in a list and then get the first two elements.

Here is your code again, with the parts I've added commented to explain what they do:

```
sentence= input("Write a sentence with two words the same: ")
findme = input("Type a word that appears twice: ")
words = sentence.split()
print (list(enumerate(words)))
print ("The length of the sentence in chracters is",len(sentence))
t = words
print("third word in sentence is:", t[2]) 

if sentence.find(findme)!=-1:
  print("found word")
else:
  print("word not found")

print (sentence.find(findme))
numberofwords = len(t)
print("The amount of words in the sentence is:",numberofwords,"words.")
print("This is the last time",findme,"is found in the sentence, its at",sentence.rfind(findme))
print (sentence.index(findme))

# Set up the variables we will need
lastFoundIndex = 0 # last position we found the word at
test_words = sentence.split() # List of words
positions = list() # list of positions

while lastFoundIndex < len(test_words):
  try: # try will try the code found in the block.
    foundPosition = test_words.index(findme, lastFoundIndex)
  except ValueError: # except catches errors from try, and then runs the code in it's block.
                     # In this case, if a ValueError is returned when we run the code in the try block,
                     # we break out of the loop.
    break;
  finally: # finally is executed after try and any corresponding excepts.
    positions.append(foundPosition) # It adds the found position to the list of positions...
    lastFoundIndex = foundPosition + 1 # and increases the lastFoundIndex.
                                       # The +1 is needed so it doesn't constantly find the word we just found.


# Replace everything after this point if you want all the positions

position1 = positions[0] + 1 # Get the positions of the first two occurrences...
position2 = positions[1] + 1 # ...and add 1 to them so they work with the code.

if position1 == 1:
  addtoword1 = "st"
elif position1 == 2:
  addtoword1 = "nd"
elif position1 == 3:
  addtoword1 = "rd"
elif position1 >=4:
  addtoword1 = "th"

if position2 == 1:
  addtoword2 = "st"
elif position2 == 2:
  addtoword2 = "nd"
elif position2 == 3:
  addtoword2 = "rd"
elif position2 >=4:
  addtoword2 = "th"

print ("The word",findme,"is the",position1,addtoword1,"and",position2,addtoword2,"position word in the sentence.")
print ("The word",findme,"appears",len(positions),"times in the sentence provided.")
```

Keep in mind that it only shows the positions for the first and second occurences of the word. If you want all of them, replace the code after the commented point that says `Replace everything after this point if you want all the positions` with this:

```
print("The word",findme,"is the ", end='') # end='' means that it doesn't end with a newline

wordingIndex = 1 # What item of the list we are on. Used for wording purposes

for position in positions: # Loop through all the elements

  position = position + 1

  if position == 1:
    addtoword = "st"
  elif position == 2:
    addtoword = "nd"
  elif position == 3:
    addtoword = "rd"
  else:
    addtoword = "th"

  # Now we word the sentence properly.
  if wordingIndex == len(positions): # If we're at the final position, don't add a comma
    print(position, addtoword, end='', sep='') # sep is the separator between words. It defaults to a space (' '), but
                                               # setting it to '' will make the text appear as "1st" rather than "1 st". 
  elif wordingIndex == len(positions) - 1: # If we're at the second-to-last position, add an and
    print(position, addtoword, ' and ', end='', sep='') # Keep in mind when using sep='', you have to add spaces between words and variables,
                                                        # or you'd get "1stand".
  else: # If we're anywhere else, just add a comma
    print(position, addtoword, ', ', end='', sep='')

  wordingIndex = wordingIndex + 1 # Increment the wording counter

print(" word(s) in the sentence provided.")
print ("The word",findme,"appears",len(positions),"times in the sentence provided.")
```

Also keep in mind Python requires proper indentation. So this is valid code:

```
if (someVariable == 1):
    print("That variable equals one!")
```

but this isn't:

```
if (someVariable == 1):
print("That variable equals one!") # Will not run due to indentation errors
```

Note that the first example will not work if there are less than two instances of the word.